# Add up the duplicate values

Tags: sql

I want to know the total number of tweets by the hour but it gives me duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT datepart(hh,tweet_created) AS hours_tweeted, COUNT(tweet_text) AS total_tweets
FROM [New_years_resolutions_2020]
GROUP BY tweet_created
ORDER BY total_tweets DESC;
```

| hours_tweeted | total_tweets |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 16 |
| 11 | 15 |
| 12 | 14 |
| 12 | 13 |

I want something like this

| hours_tweeted | total_tweets |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 31 |
| 12 | 27 |

Comment: MySQL is not SQL server; pick one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query to get the desired result

```
SELECT datepart(hh, tweet_created) AS hours_tweeted, COUNT(DISTINCT tweet_text) AS total_tweets
FROM [New_years_resolutions_2020]
GROUP BY datepart(hh, tweet_created)
ORDER BY total_tweets DESC;
```